# The second moment and fourth moment of $\mathcal{P}(V)$?

Tags: attack, probability

**Backgroud**: I am reading the paper "Learning a Parallelepiped: Cryptanalysis of GGH and NTRU Signatures". (here is the [link](https://cims.nyu.edu/%7Eregev/papers/gghattack.pdf)). And I got stuck in understanding the computation of moment.

**Question statement**: In section 4.3 of the paper, It defined: For any $V=[\mathbf{v}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{v}_n] \in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ and any integer $k \ge 1$, the $k$-th moment of $\mathcal{P}(V)$ over a vector $\mathbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is
$$\text{mom}_{V,k}(\mathbf{w}) = \mathbb{E}[\langle\mathbf{u},\mathbf{w}\rangle ^k]$$
where $\mathbf{u}$ is uniformly distributed over the parallelepiped $\mathcal{P}(V)$.
Then authors said a straightforward calculation shows that for any $\mathbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, second moments and fourth moments are
$$\text{mom}_{V,2}(\mathbf{w}) = \frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \langle \mathbf{v}_i,\mathbf{w}\rangle^2 =\frac{1}{3}\mathbf{w}V^tV\mathbf{w}^t$$

$$\text{mom}_{V,4}(\mathbf{w}) = \frac{1}{5}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \langle \mathbf{v}_i,\mathbf{w}\rangle^4 + \frac{1}{3}\sum_{i \neq j} \langle \mathbf{v}_i,\mathbf{w}\rangle^2  \langle \mathbf{v}_j,\mathbf{w}\rangle^2$$

But it seems not such straightforward for me... I have trouble in understanding  the calculation of these second and fourth moments.

**My effort**: For second moment, by the definition, we have
$$\text{mom}_{V,2} = \mathbb{E}[\langle\mathbf{u},\mathbf{w}\rangle ^2] = \int \langle\mathbf{u},\mathbf{w}\rangle ^2 f(\mathbf{u}) \text{d}\mathbf{u} = \frac{1}{|\mathcal{P}(V)|} \int \langle\mathbf{u},\mathbf{w}\rangle ^2 \text{d}\mathbf{u}$$

the last equality is because $\mathbf{u}$ is uniformly distributed over the parallelepiped $\mathcal{P}(V)$. Now I can't move forward. The same is  fourth moments.

Any hints would be helpful.

Comment: The notation looked annoyingly like exponential function, but I believe it is the expectation operator. Feel free to undo if I misinterpreted

Comment: @kodlu, yes ,it is expectation operator, the original paper used Exp notation so I copied here. The notation you edited makes it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's instructive to look at the proof of Lemma 1 where $\mathbf v$ is rewritten $\mathbf u=\mathbf xV$ where $\mathbf x$ is a uniform sample from $[-1,1]^n$. Thus
$$\mathbb E(\langle \mathbf u,\mathbf w\rangle^2)=\mathbb E_{\mathbf u}(\mathbf w\mathbf  u^T\mathbf u\mathbf w^T)=\mathbf wV^T\mathbb E_{\mathbf x}(\mathbf x^T\mathbf x)V\mathbf w^T.$$

The expectation of $\mathbf x^T\mathbf x$ is the covariance matrix of $n$ i.i.d. uniform random variables on $[-1,1]$. Independence means that the off-diagonal terms are 0 and that the diagonal terms are
$$\mathbb E(X^2)=\frac12\int_{-1}^1t^2dt=\frac 13$$
where $X$ is a random variable uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$. So that
$$\mathbb E_{\mathbf x}(\mathbf x^T\mathbf x)=\frac13 I_n$$
and so
$$\mathbb E(\langle \mathbf u,\mathbf w\rangle^2)=\frac13\mathbf wV^TV\mathbf w^T$$
as claimed.

I haven't fully expanded out the 4th moment, but again the terms will be integrals products of i.i.d. random variables $X_iX_jX_kX_\ell$ uniform on $[-1,1]$. Terms where any variable is represented to an odd power will be zero which only leaves terms $X_i^4$ and $X_i^2X_j^2$ with $i\neq j$. These should correspond to the two sums.

Comment: Got this! I am trying to find the relation of $\text{mom}_{V,2}(\mathbf{w})$ and $\frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \langle \mathbf{v}_i,\mathbf{w}\rangle^2$ first. Then try to find the relation of $\frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \langle \mathbf{v}_i,\mathbf{w}\rangle^2$ and $\frac{1}{3}\mathbf{w}V^tV\mathbf{w}^t$.

Comment: But it seems the relation should be $\mathbf{w}V^tV\mathbf{w}^t$ = $(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \langle \mathbf{v}_i,\mathbf{w}\rangle)^2$.  That is $\mathbf{w}V^tV\mathbf{w}^t = (w_1,\cdots, w_n)(\mathbf{v}_1^t,\cdots,\mathbf{v}_n^t)^t(\mathbf{v}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{v}_n)(w_1,\cdots,w_n)^t = (w_1\mathbf{v}_1^T+\cdots+w_n\mathbf{v}_n^t) (\mathbf{v}_1w_1+\cdots+\mathbf{v}_nw_n) =(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \langle \mathbf{v}_i,\mathbf{w}\rangle)^2 $.

Comment: Please corret me if am wrong.

Comment: It seems another question. Should I put this in the question body?

Comment: @zbo Your identity $\sum\langle\mathbf v_i,\mathbf w\rangle^2=\mathbf V^TV\mathbf w^T$ is indeed correct by the definition of matrix multiplication. Hence $\mathrm{mom_V,2}(\mathbf w)=\mathbf wV^TV\mathbf w^T$ as in my answer also proves that $\mathrm{mom}_{V,2}(\mathbf w)=\sum\langle\mathbf v_i,\mathbf w\rangle^2$.

Comment: Hi, This is what I am confused. The matrix multiplication. I think it should be 
$\sum_{i=1}^n \langle\mathbf{v}_i,\mathbf{w} \rangle ^2 = \mathbf{w} VV^T \mathbf{w}^T$. Not $\mathbf{w} V^TV \mathbf{w}^T$
. Since $VV^T = \mathbf{v}_1\mathbf{v_1}^T +  \mathbf{v}_2\mathbf{v_2}^T + \cdots +  \mathbf{v}_n\mathbf{v_n}^T$. But $V^T V $ is actually a matrix form. Since $V$ is a 1*n matrix form of colunm vector.

Comment: My mistake. The authors said Vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$ will be row vectors denoted by bold lowercase letters. I think they are trying to let $V$ be form of row vectors $\mathbf{v}_1,\cdots, \mathbf{v}_n$. So $V^TV = \mathbf{v}_1^T\mathbf{v}_1+\cdots+\mathbf{v}_n^T\mathbf{v}_n$